# Brew versions unknown command mavericks

Tags: homebrew, zsh

I´m having problems with the brew versions command, I´m trying to run

```
brew versions grails
Error: Unknown command: versions

 which brew                               127 ↵
/usr/local/bin/brew

brew -v
Homebrew 0.9.5
```

Comment: Try this first `brew tap homebrew/boneyard` as `versions` is obsolete.

Comment: worked as a charm! thanks!,answer that to accept as answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this first:

```
brew tap homebrew/boneyard
```

as `versions` option is obsolete.

Comment: Any idea why it has been obsoleted? Is there a replacement or is it considered "bad"?

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE: they've started putting multiple versions in homebrew-core ([see the message here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions)), so now you'll see it by default:

```
$ brew update
$ brew search grails
grails                             grails@2.5
```

---

Info about the deprecated "homebrew/versions":

The `versions` command was obsoleted in favor of [homebrew-versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions), which is a separate tap with formulas pointing to specific versions of packages. You can add it with `brew tap homebrew/versions` and `brew update`, then you'll see specific versions from the tap like this:

```
$ brew search grails
grails                        homebrew/versions/grails20    homebrew/versions/grails22
homebrew/versions/grails224   homebrew/versions/grails13    homebrew/versions/grails21
homebrew/versions/grails223   homebrew/versions/grails23
$ brew install homebrew/versions/grails223
```

You can also look at the git commit log from the regular tap and pick a version that way:

```
$ brew log grails
commit eeacedb303093999c60d5696e3385213021dc1eb
Author: Christian-Manuel Butzke <chris@fruwe.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 27 10:28:42 2016 +0900
    grails 3.0.12
    Closes #48501.
    Signed-off-by: Martin Afanasjew <martin@afanasjew.de>

commit bbdbbe29827d77e5f530d804a07e9985f74d8cbe
Author: Xu Cheng <xucheng@me.com>
. . .
$ cd $(brew --prefix)
$ git checkout bbdbbe29827d77e5f530d804a07e9985f74d8cbe Library/Formula/grails.rb
$ brew install grails
```

Comment: `homebrew/versions` as in Mike Placentra's answer above is also no longer available.

If anyone has a newer method of restoring this functionality, please update.

Comment: @LonnyEachus You're right, they deprecated `homebrew/versions`. I just updated my answer with the new solution.

Comment: What do I do if another process (`rvm requirements` in this case) insists on using `brew tap homebrew/versions`? It causes the error every time and I'm at my wit's end. :(

Comment: I'm using Homebrew 3.1.5. Search does *not* display the version. i.e. ```$ brew search grails
==> Formulae
grails
``` I am completely at a loss to figuring out how to find available versions. homebrew/versions is gone, it's a 404 so no further leads.

Answer (score 7):

When I ran `brew tap homebrew/boneyard` and then `brew versions node` I got the following, which looks like the proper replacement:

> You should use the homebrew-versions tap instead:
>   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I noticed also that for example in grails, brew versions have more avaible version that the homebrew-versions.